# GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection pod iOS crash

Tags: ios, swift, face-detection, google-mlkit

I am facing an issue when debugging the MLKit FaceDetection.

When the code detects a face it crashes

```swift
faceDetector.process(visionImage) { [weak self] (faces, error) in
            
            guard let self = self, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            // Detect Face
            guard let faces = faces, !faces.isEmpty, faces.count == 1, let face = faces.first else {}
}
```

[image]

This is the crash
**Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
Expected MLKFace but found MLKFace**

Run the application by cable with debug scheme

I installed the latest version from below Pod
pod 'GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection'

Comment: what's the actual faces.count before the line of "// Detect Face"?

Comment: one face object

Comment: 1. I verified that when there is one face returned in the result, it is an array of one face, instead of one face object in `faces`.

2. Your code is slightly different from https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/VisionExample/ViewController.swift#L692-L705, have you tried it in the original VisionExample app? Does it crash too?